# Color format calculated currency column in SharePoint List if formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, calculated-column, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am trying to format this calculated column to show if a number is more than or equal to format it green, or if it is less than or equal to 0 format it red?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "if a number is greater than 0, format it green and if it is less than or equal to 0, format it red"?

Comment: Hi, yes exactly, I have been trying to find the string and cant get it! :(

Comment: check my answer given below. let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this JSON in column formatting option for this column:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "padding-left": "10px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField > 0, 'sp-field-severity--good', if(@currentField == 0 || @currentField < 0, 'sp-field-severity--blocked', '') + ' ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary'"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField.displayValue"
    }
  ]
}
```

**OR**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "padding-left": "10px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField > 0, 'sp-field-severity--good', 'sp-field-severity--blocked') + ' ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary'"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField.displayValue"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)